# Is ${(prime^2-1) \over 24}$ always a member of the generalized pentagonal number set?

Tags: prime-numbers

I was working through a puzzle on why the square of a prime minus one is always a factor of 24 (http://puzzles.nigelcoldwell.co.uk/fifteen.htm) and noticed that the sequence of numbers for ${(prime^2-1) \over 24}$ always seems to be a member of the generalized pentagonal number set (http://oeis.org/A001318).

For example, the first 70 members of the set of ${(prime^2-1) \over 24}$ are:

0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 15, 22, 35, 40, 57, 70, 77, 92, 117, 145, 155, 187, 210, 222, 260, 287, 330, 392, 425, 442, 477, 495, 532, 672, 715, 782, 805, 925, 950, 1027, 1107, 1162, 1247, 1335, 1365, 1520, 1552, 1617, 1650, 1855, 2072, 2147, 2185, 2262, 2380, 2420, 2625, 2752, 2882, 3015, 3060, 3197, 3290, 3337, 3577, 3927, 4030, 4082, 4187, 4565, 4732, 5017, 5075, 5192, 5370, 5612, 5797, 5985, 6112, 6305, 6567, 6700, 6970, 7315, 7385, 7740, 7812, 8030, 8177, 8400, 8702, 8855, 8932, 9087, 9560, 9882, 10045, 10375, 10542, 10795, 11310, 11397, 12195

And the first 181 members of the generalized pentagonal set are (bolded members are also a member of ${(prime^2-1) \over 24}$:

**0** **1** **2** **5** **7** **12** **15** **22** 26 **35** **40** 51 **57** **70** **77** **92** 100 **117** 126 **145** **155** 176 **187** **210** **222** 247 **260** **287** 301 **330** 345 376 **392** **425** **442** **477** **495** **532** 551 590 610 651 **672** **715** 737 **782** **805** 852 876 **925** **950** 1001 **1027** 1080 **1107** **1162** 1190 **1247** 1276 **1335** **1365** 1426 1457 **1520** **1552** **1617** **1650** 1717 1751 1820 **1855** 1926 1962 2035 **2072** **2147** **2185** **2262** 2301 **2380** **2420** 2501 2542 **2625** 2667 **2752** 2795 **2882** 2926 **3015** **3060** 3151 **3197** **3290** **3337** 3432 3480 **3577** 3626 3725 3775 3876 **3927** **4030** **4082** **4187** 4240 4347 4401 4510 **4565** 4676 **4732** 4845 4902 **5017** **5075** **5192** 5251 **5370** 5430 5551 **5612** 5735 **5797** 5922 **5985** **6112** 6176 **6305** 6370 6501 **6567** **6700** 6767 6902 **6970** 7107 7176 **7315** **7385** 7526 7597 **7740** **7812** 7957 **8030** **8177** 8251 **8400** 8475 8626 **8702** **8855** **8932** **9087** 9165 9322 9401 **9560** 9640 9801 **9882** **10045** 10127 10292 **10375** **10542** 10626 **10795** 10880 11051 11137 **11310** **11397** 11572 11660 11837 11926 12105 **12195**

I verified that this was true for the first 600 primes, but is this true generally?

Comment: I think the answer has something to do with the pentagonal number set being related to coprimes of 24, but I just can't figure out how to connect the dots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, $24\mid(n^2-1)\Leftrightarrow 3,8\mid(n^2-1)$ by CRT, which is easy to very mod $3$, $8$ so long as we have $n\ge5$. This holds regardless of whether or not $n$ is prime, so primes are a red herring here.

Secondly, solving

$$\frac{n^2-1}{24}=\frac{k(3k-1)}{2}$$

for $k$ yields $k=\frac{1\pm n}{6}$, so in particular $\frac{n^2-1}{24}$ is generalized pentagonal iff $n\equiv\pm1$ mod $6$.